# How to disable/enable a specific USB port in windows with python?

Tags: python, windows

I want to create a toggle switch in graphical window that can Disable/Enable specific USB port in windows with python, which external command or library can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`devcon.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon):

```
import subprocess
# Fetches the list of all usb devices:
result = subprocess.run(['devcon', 'hwids', '=usb'], 
    capture_output=True, text=True)

# ... add code to parse the result and get the hwid of the device you want ...

subprocess.run(['devcon', 'disable', parsed_hwid]) # to disable
subprocess.run(['devcon', 'enable', parsed_hwid]) # to enable
```

Comment: Is that a Windows command? I get *`'devcon' is not recognized as an internal or external command`*.

Comment: @jww  please click the link I added to the answer - it explains how to get `devcon.exe` directly from microsoft