# Turn ON/OFF the power to a USB port in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, usb

Is it possible to control the power to a USB port using a python2.7-script?

I have tried Nolan Foster answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64991005/11939486), but the `subprocess.run` only works with python 3

Comment: No, subprocess also works for Python 2.7


```Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec 21 2020, 23:00:36) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.30.4) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=sign+stri on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import subprocess
>>> 
```

However, in the link it uses **subprocess.run** which is introduced in *python3*

Comment: @vikashkumar, thanks. The question is edited.